# How to start a process and then run shell commands within that process using python?

Tags: python, subprocess

I am currently trying to write a python script that will start osquery and then conduct a query - all I have for my script so far is:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(["osqueryi"])
```

The problem is that once I run "osqueryi", I have to do the query (which is only one command) from within the command line, which I have no idea how to do in Python as I don't know how to wait for "osqueryi" to finish and then run a new command within that process (sorry if my terminology is off, still very new to all this!).

Normally, it would go:

```
  a@b: osqueryi
  osquery> select * from processes
```

Does anybody know how I could go about this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score -1):

https://osquery.readthedocs.io/en/stable/introduction/using-osqueryi/

By passing your query to osquery as parameter.